# export to CSV at the end of the run

Tags: javascript, while-loop, puppeteer, export-to-csv, do-while

The original code that scrape the first page of data works but then I created a loop that clicks on a "load more" button and then scrapes the data until there is no more "load more" button. At the end of my run it is not exporting anything. Is my code for exporting to CSV incorrect? Where am I going wrong with this?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const jsonexport = require('jsonexport');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false }); // default is true
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.Website.com/exercises/finder', {
    waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded',
  });

  //load more CSS to be targeted
  const LoadMoreButton =
    '#js-ex-content > #js-ex-category-body > .ExCategory-results > .ExLoadMore > .bb-flat-btn';

  do {
// clicking load more button and waiting 1sec
    await page.click(LoadMoreButton);
    await page.waitFor(1000);

    const loadMore = true;


    const rowsCounts = await page.$eval(
      '.ExCategory-results > .ExResult-row',
      (rows) => rows.length
    );

    //scraping the data
    const exerciseNames = [];
    for (let i = 2; i < rowsCounts + 1; i++) {
      const exerciseName = await page.$eval(
        `.ExCategory-results > .ExResult-row:nth-child(${i}) > .ExResult-cell > .ExHeading > a`,
        (el) => el.innerText
      );
      exerciseNames.push(exerciseName);
    }

    console.log({exerciseNames});
  } while (10000);

  const allData = [
    {
      exercise: exerciseNames,
    },
  ];
// exporting data to CSV
  const options = [exercise];
  //json export error part
  jsonexport(allData, options, function (err, csv) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(csv);
  });

  await browser.close();
})().catch((e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
```

**Edit:**
This is what I have at the moment for the exporting and writing to a CSV file. I'm getting 3 headers but only the exercises are being written and then nothing else. Console.log shows exercises, muscle target group, and equipments being exported though. I'm trying to get it where they are 3 headers (name, equipment, and targeted muscle) and then each row is being filled inside of it. Ex: squat, barbell, legs these would be in one row  but each in their own cell.

Current export code:

```
 const allData = [
    {
      exercise: exerciseNames,
      muscleGroup: muscleTargets,
      equipment: equipmentTypes,
    },
  ];

  var ws = fs.createWriteStream('test1.csv');


  csv.write(allData, { headers: true, delimiter: ',' }).pipe(ws);

  //json export error part
  jsonexport(allData, function (err, csv) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(csv);
  });
```

[image]

**Edit 2**
This is currently my entire code. It is outputting the allData pre-filled info but no more new data

```
 const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const jsonexport = require('jsonexport');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false }); // default is true
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.website.com/exercises/finder', {
    waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded',
  });

  const loadMore = true;

  const rowsCounts = await page.$$eval(
    '.ExCategory-results > .ExResult-row',
    (rows) => rows.length
  );
  let allData = [];
  for (let i = 2; i < rowsCounts + 1; i++) {
    const exerciseName = await page.$eval(
      `.ExCategory-results > .ExResult-row:nth-child(${i}) > .ExResult-cell > .ExHeading > a`,
      (el) => el.innerText
    );
    const muscleGroupName = await page.$eval(
      `.ExCategory-results > .ExResult-row:nth-child(${i}) > .ExResult-cell > .ExResult-muscleTargeted > a`,
      (el) => el.innerHTML
    );
    const equipmentName = await page.$eval(
      `.ExCategory-results > .ExResult-row:nth-child(${i}) > .ExResult-cell > .ExResult-equipmentType > a`,
      (el) => el.innerHTML
    );

    let obj = {
      exercise: exerciseName,
      muscleGroup: muscleGroupName,
      equipment: equipmentName,
    };
    allData.push(obj);
  }
  console.log(allData);

  async function fn() {
    const allData = [
      {
        exercise: 'Rickshaw Carry',
        muscleGroup: 'Forearms',
        equipment: 'Other',
      },
      {
        exercise: 'Single-Leg Press',
        muscleGroup: 'Quadriceps',
        equipment: 'Machine',
      },
      {
        exercise: 'Landmine twist',
        muscleGroup: 'Forearms',
        equipment: 'Other',
      },
      {
        exercise: 'Weighted pull-up',
        muscleGroup: 'Forearms',
        equipment: 'Other',
      },
    ];

    // json export error part
    jsonexport(allData, function (err, csv) {
      if (err) return console.error(err);
      console.log(csv);
      fs.writeFileSync('output.csv', csv);
    });
  }
  fn();

  await browser.close();
})().catch((e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
```

Comment: We need more information. What actually happens? Does the code log an error? One line that sticks out is "const options = [exercise];" What is exercise? It doesn't seem like you declare it.


Just as a crazy suggestion, you could try removing the options parameter, as it doesn't seem necessary and could be causing a problem. IDK though. I don't really have the info to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two issues here.

**I.)** One of them is with the `options` declaration:

```
const options = [exercise]; // ❌
```

You are trying to access the `exercise` property of `allData` object without a proper notation. If you really need to extract it inside a new array you can do it by going inside the first element of the `allData` array using index `[0]`, then using the [dot-notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) to access the `exercise` property.

```
const options = [allData[0].exercise]; // ✅
```

*Note:* I suggest to leave the options simply `allData[0].exercise` (without the wrapping array) as your `allData` object is already an array, I see no benefit of making the structure deeper.

---

**II.)** The second issue is with the usage of [jsonexport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonexport) npm package. I suppose you left `allData` accidentally in this line:

```
jsonexport(allData, options, function (err, csv) // ❌
```

You only need the `options` here (as according to the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonexport) you can give only one object as the input):

```
jsonexport(options, function (err, csv) // ✅
```

---

### Edit

Based on your updated answer your problem can be solved if you restructure a bit your `allData` object, so the jsonexport will recognize each column and row correctly.

```js
const jsonexport = require('jsonexport')
const fs = require('fs')

async function fn() {
  const allData = [
    {
      exercise: 'Rickshaw Carry',
      muscleGroup: 'Forearms',
      equipment: 'Other'
    },
    {
      exercise: 'Single-Leg Press',
      muscleGroup: 'Quadriceps',
      equipment: 'Machine'
    },
    {
      exercise: 'Landmine twist',
      muscleGroup: 'Forearms',
      equipment: 'Other'
    },
    {
      exercise: 'Weighted pull-up',
      muscleGroup: 'Forearms',
      equipment: 'Other'
    }
  ]

  // json export error part
  jsonexport(allData, function (err, csv) {
    if (err) return console.error(err)
    console.log(csv)
    fs.writeFileSync('output.csv', csv)
  })
}
fn()
```

To achieve such structure you should extend `allData` in each iteration like this:

```js
let allData = []
for (let i = 2; i < rowsCounts; i++) {
  const exerciseName = await page.$eval(`...row:nth-child(${i})...`,
    el => el.textContent.trim())
  const muscleGroupName = await page.$eval(`...row:nth-child(${i})...`,
    el => el.textContent.trim())
  const equipmentName = await page.$eval(`...row:nth-child(${i})...`,
    el => el.textContent.trim())

  let obj = {
    exercise: exerciseName,
    muscleGroup: muscleGroupName,
    equipment: equipmentName
  }
  allData.push(obj)
}
console.log(allData)
```

Comment: For options I thought it was because it would export a column exercise and each row would be exerciseNames. I also don't understand how it would export it as an CSV file. But after researching some more, would I be needing to import fs for it to create a CSV file? 
Sorry about all of the question I'm just new to this and confused. As always, thank you for all the help.

Comment: I see. I suggest to check out the examples at https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonexport and try to implement a similar structure, mybe experiment a bit first. If you are struggling with it: it may worth a new question on stackover. And yes, you will need "fs" module to save your csv file. Something like this: `fs.writeFileSync('output.csv', csvObject)` (if your csvObject is the output of the `jsonexport` function)

Comment: Now I checked back a bit your code: in this case you may need `allData` only and not `options` like: `jsonexport(allData, function (err, csv)` and it will have the headings. But these could be answered if we would see an example `allData` object, currently we are unable to run the same script (as it is about "exampleSite.com"). It is not a problem, but it's very hard to figure that part. without the actual data you want to convert.

Comment: I spent all day trying to figure it out but now i'm truly stuck now. I update the website and posted the current code that I have for exporting.

Comment: OK, see my edited answer. It may help. FYI: I shortened the selectors in the loop, also you may need to align my code to yours a bit. I hope it helps.

Comment: Oh that makes sense but I'm a little confused for the allData output. If I run it like this it will create an output.csv file with the mentioned exercises, equipment, and muscle groups (which makes sense). If I replace those with what's in the object then it would create a file with those headers but only fill out the exercise name. To have thoe get filled up as more data is being pulled in what would I need to call within allData? 

I hope that made sense.

Comment: The current code snippets does exactly this (just with a prefilled data in the example). I suggest to try to run them and see if the results in the csv satisfy your needs. If you build the `allData` object in the for loop you don't need to call anything within the `allData`. Later I can extend my answer with more explanations and MDN references about js objects. In the meantime I suggest to try to run these snippets in their own just to see how it works.

Comment: I updated my question and it shows my entire code that I have at the moment. I have ran it but it only outputs what is prefilled.

Comment: OK, you have followed too strictly my examples. You are defining `allData` twice, and the second one overrides what you've collected with puppeteer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217832/discussion-between-thedavidbarton-and-bruce-mathers).

Comment: hi @BruceMathers, have you been able to solve it in the meantime?

Comment: Yes I did! I uploaded it to google sheets and it showed all of the data...I have no idea why it didn't show it in excel. Kind of embarrassed of taking so much of your time.